# Cracking DES(Unix)/MD5 ARP

Tags: cryptanalysis, des, md5

This is a basic example of an Unix Pass Encryption.

I have a little Hash of MD5 ARP:

```
user50:$apr1$w7YNTrjQ$0/71H7ze5o9/jCnKLt0mj0
user60:$apr1$AIw2h09/$Ti0TRlU9mDpCGm5zg.ZDP.
```

I need to find the pass of two users: user50 & user60.

I was wondering, what is the best way to crack this hash? Maybe with John the Ripper? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest John the Ripper. Get a large dictionary file and run it through John. You could even split it among multiple machines (possibly in the cloud) as the problem is very parallelizable.

John can even do variations on dictionary words like substituting 0 for o.

For more info, see [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-password-cracking-john-the-ripper/).

If you have access to a GPU, [oclHashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/) looks interesting.

Comment: Well i use John the ripper. I know the length of the pass is : 7. I try to configure John for search only pass with lenght = 7, but i don't find the option... Do you know what is the option ?

Comment: Take your dictionary file and run it through john with --stdout=7. This will produce a dictionary file where all passwords are no more than 7 characters. See [EXAMPLES](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/EXAMPLES.shtml) (search for --stdout on that page and you will see an example).

Comment: Yeah, --stdout only work with a wordlist, it's not possible with basic option like ../john --stdout=7 pass

Comment: See this then: http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/CONFIG.shtml and look at "Incremental" mode parameters

Comment: the documentation looks like years 1995...